# Webcam not working on Production, not showing permits popup

Tags: reactjs, browser, webcam

I have a project using React but the component WebCam that works perfectly in all browsers locally; but when tested in a server, doesn't show the permits pop-up to allow the use of the camera.

I don't think the code is the problem. Instead some security on the browsers. I tried to give permissions directly to the site on Chrome and I can't change it. And is not blocked, on either browser.

Some other considerations:

I haven't install any ssl certificate, is just a small testing server to play, so I wasn't thinking to install them for the moment.

could this be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getUserMedia` API requires you to serve the page over HTTPS (or on localhost). So if you haven’t set that up, that is why it’s not working in production.

See the Security section of this documentation for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#security

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this? Or any free way to install an SSL certificate?
Letsencrypt and zerossl don't issue certificates for bare ip's... And I was avoiding to get a domain for this server. Or any other suggestion?

Comment: I’d get a domain, or, if you already have another domain, set up a subdomain that you could use. When you launch this application you’re going to need a domain and SSL cert anyway.